Cookie script button got replaced (overwritten) by another script button
During my QA testing of a website, I have encountered the following error:

I'm encountering an issue with a button in the footer of my site related to cookie consent. Initially, when the page loads, the footer shows a "Cookie preferences" button that should trigger the OneTrust cookie popup for managing consent preferences. However, after the page fully loads, this button suddenly changes to a "Learn more" button. This behavior occurs every time I reload the page.
Upon inspecting the network tab in my browser, I noticed that a JavaScript error consistently appears, and immediately after, the button in the footer switches from "Cookie preferences" to "Learn more." Both buttons trigger the same OneTrust cookie popup, which is confusing because the "Cookie preferences" button should be the one displayed.
Based on my observations, it seems like one cookie script is overwriting the other. The "Learn more" button is the one shown to first-time visitors, prompting them to confirm their cookie preferences (check the screenshot below). 
I'm trying to understand why this button replacement happens and how to fix the script conflict. I cannot really guarantee that the overwriting is causing the error; I'm just guessing that. What I'm sure is that this isn't a cache error.
